# update actual values using pass by value

Tags: c, function, pass-by-value

I want to know if there is any way to update original values by using pass by value.

Also i want to know if I can return updated address back to main

Here I dont want to use pass by reference to swap original values in main.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int a = 100;
int f =200;
int *p, * q;
swap(int, int);

main()
     {
    printf("%d %d\n", a,f);
    swap(a, f);

    printf("%d %d\n",a ,f); //values remain same here how to change them
    }

     swap(int a, int f)
    {
        int t;
        p=&a;
        q=&f;

        t=*p;
        *p=*q;
        *q= t;

    printf("%d %d\n",a ,f);
    }
```

Comment: No. Reference semantics can be implemented in C using pointer parameters and address-of operations; the pointers get passed by value in that arrangement.

Comment: Please format your code.

Comment: You *could* use a macro instead of a function.

Comment: Use Structure to return swaped values to calling function

Answer (score 2):

> I want to know if there is any way to update original values by using pass by value.

Yes there is, you need to pass a pointer:

```
void swap(int* a, int* b)
{
    int temp = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = temp;
}
```

And call it like this:

```
swap(&a, &f);
```

Note that there's no pass-by-reference in C, that's a C++ feature. In C *everything*, including pointers, are passed by value.

And pass-by-value means *copy* in C, so it's impossible to modify what was passed.

> Also i want to know if I can return updated address back to main

Yes you can. Just change the function return type to a pointer type and add a return statement with the address of the variable of your choice.

Comment: I want to do by pass by value

Comment: @niyasc There is only pass by value in C. The pointers are passed by value.

Comment: @tuple_cat swap(&a, &f) is pass by reference

Comment: @tuple_cat But you're passing address of variable as value. Such cases are refered as pass by reference in C. http://www.cs.usfca.edu/~wolber/SoftwareDev/C/paramPassing.htm.

Comment: @SourceCode: Nonsense. It's taking the address of two values and then passing that address by value.

Comment: If you want to know whether it's possible to implement swap without using the address-of operation, then no, it's not possible.

Comment: @SourceCode  It depends on how you look at it.  It is addresses that are clearly being passed to swap - and they are being passed by value so they cannot be updated.  It is just a side effect that the address of something can be used to update it.

Comment: @JerryJeremiah Indeed.  The address is passed *by value* and then used to update *something else* - that wasn't even passed.  It's *not* "pass by reference" at all.